# Match elements in nested list with values from dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list

```
l = [['a', 's', 'l'], ['a', 'g', 'l'], ['a', 's', 'l'], ['g', 's', 'l'], ['a', 'l', 'g']]
```

I also have a dictionary

```
d = [{'a': 1, 'v': 6, 'c': 7}, {'g': 3, 's': 4, 'l': 9}]
```

I need to create another list in the shape of `l` but with the values matched from `d`:

```
d = [[1, 4 ,9], [1, 3 , 9], [1, 4 , 9], [3, 4 , 9], [1, 9 , 3]]
```

I have tried using for loops to do this but the nested list is giving me trouble.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your expected output? Some more information about what exactly you are trying to accomplish would be helpful.

Comment: Can all the dictionaries in `d` be combined? (presumably so, otherwise the answer would be ambiguous)

Comment: Also, `l` and `d` are poorly formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `d` really is a list of dicts, so you should merge the list of dicts into one dict first, and then use a list comprehension to map the items in the sub-lists to their dict values:

```
d = dict(i for s in d for i in s.items())
print([list(map(d.get, s)) for s in l])
```

so that given:

```
l = [['a', 's' ,'l'], ['a', 'g' , 'l'], ['a', 's' , 'l'], ['g', 's' , 'l'], ['a', 'l' , 'g']]
d = [{'a': 1, 'v': 6, 'c': 7}, {'g': 3, 's': 4, 'l': 9}]
```

This outputs:

```
[[1, 4, 9], [1, 3, 9], [1, 4, 9], [3, 4, 9], [1, 9, 3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple comprehensions will work:

```
combined_mapping = {k: v for subdict in d for k, v in subdict.items()}
mapped = [[combined_mapping[element] for element in sublist] for sublist in l]
mapped
```

Output:

```
[[1, 4, 9], [1, 3, 9], [1, 4, 9], [3, 4, 9], [1, 9, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why your `d` variable is actually a list of dictionaries.  It it was an actual dictionary this would be very straightforward:

```
l = [['a', 's', 'l'], ['a', 'g', 'l'], ['a', 's', 'l'], ['g', 's', 'l'], ['a', 'l', 'g']]
d = {'a': 1, 'v': 6, 'c': 7, 'g': 3, 's': 4, 'l': 9}

r = [ [d[v] for v in lv] for lv in l ]
print(r) # [[1, 4, 9], [1, 3, 9], [1, 4, 9], [3, 4, 9], [1, 9, 3]]
```